# Using UTF8 in oracle tables linked to MS Access

Tags: oracle, ms-access, utf-8, odbc

UTF8 characters are not showing in my linked tables on an Oracle database.
(They're even causing access to have problems getting a lock on records)

I tried adding `"charset=utf8"` to the connection string, but so far it did not work.

I thought I'd try this query when the program runs:

`SET NAMES utf8`

But how do I run it on the remote Oracle server through the same connection as the linked tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Oracle ODBC on Windows myself but I do use various Oracle ODBC drivers on a number of UNIX operating systems. You don't say which ODBC driver you are using but are you sure it has a connection attribute charset=utf8? The Oracle ODBC driver for Linux does not seem to have this attribute. Also, I've not heard of "set names utf8" for Oracle; isn't that a mysql thing?

In UNIX to get UTF-8 data back from Oracle you set your NLS_LANG environment variable to something like AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8 which tells the Oracle client libs how you want the data.

As an aside, ODBC doesn't really do UTF-8 very well (explanation too long for here). ODBC drivers on Windows use the so called wide APIs SQLxxxW which take and return SQLWCHARs which are 2 bytes in size and usually UCS-2 encoded. A Unicode compliant driver on Windows should provide the SQLxxxW wide APIs and UTF-8 does not come into it.

However, as I said, I don't use Oracle on Windows but some of the above might help you.

Comment: That did it! I used a little VBA to set the environment variable at boot (found here: http://www.eileenslounge.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=4857 ) and it's working fine now.